# Flicking of white page when opening a new page in firefox (high constrast mode)

Tags: windows, firefox, colors, white-screen

I am using high-contrast mode in Windows 7 x64. All the background opens in black, but just before the page loads, the page is full of white. Can I change it to black instead?

On a side note, I also tried Google Chrome with [High Contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) extension, and I have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the background color from

```
Right click on the desktop > Personalize  
Click on Windows Color (Set to high contrast)  
Under Item: select Application Background
```

Set to it to the color you want. In my case it was black.